# Unit of Measure Conversion Library

Tags: javascript

What is the best/most elegant way to abstract out the conversion of units of measures in the client, based on a user-preferred unit of measure setting?

For example, let's say user A's preferred unit of measure is "metric", while user's B's preference is "imperial".

Now lets say I've calculated the area of something in meters squared. When I go to display the value I need to use different conversion factors for each user (eg, "1 meter = 1.09361 yards"). Or say I've calculated the fluid volume in `mL`. User B's view will get calculated using the conversion "236.588237 mL = 1 US cup".

Is there an existing javascript library that anyone here knows about that handles these trivial UOM conversions?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's a little script I threw together just for the heck of it. It handles all the SI conversions for grams, bytes, meters and liters, and also I've added ounces and pounds as an example of non-SI units. To add more, you'll need to:

1. Add the base type to the "units" list for items that follow SI or
2. Add the conversion ratios for items that don't follow SI

Usage:

```
$u(1, 'g').as('kg').val(); // converts one gram to kg
```

You can get the value out with .val(), a string representation using .toString() or the full details via .debug()

```
(function () {
    var table = {};

    window.unitConverter = function (value, unit) {
        this.value = value;
        if (unit) {
            this.currentUnit = unit;
        }
    };
    unitConverter.prototype.as = function (targetUnit) {
        this.targetUnit = targetUnit;
        return this;
    };
    unitConverter.prototype.is = function (currentUnit) {
        this.currentUnit = currentUnit;
        return this;
    };

    unitConverter.prototype.val = function () {
        // first, convert from the current value to the base unit
        var target = table[this.targetUnit];
        var current = table[this.currentUnit];
        if (target.base != current.base) {
            throw new Error('Incompatible units; cannot convert from "' + this.currentUnit + '" to "' + this.targetUnit + '"');
        }

        return this.value * (current.multiplier / target.multiplier);
    };
    unitConverter.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.val() + ' ' + this.targetUnit;
    };
    unitConverter.prototype.debug = function () {
        return this.value + ' ' + this.currentUnit + ' is ' + this.val() + ' ' + this.targetUnit;
    };
    unitConverter.addUnit = function (baseUnit, actualUnit, multiplier) {
        table[actualUnit] = { base: baseUnit, actual: actualUnit, multiplier: multiplier };
    };

    var prefixes = ['Y', 'Z', 'E', 'P', 'T', 'G', 'M', 'k', 'h', 'da', '', 'd', 'c', 'm', 'u', 'n', 'p', 'f', 'a', 'z', 'y'];
    var factors = [24, 21, 18, 15, 12, 9, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -6, -9, -12, -15, -18, -21, -24];
    // SI units only, that follow the mg/kg/dg/cg type of format
    var units = ['g', 'b', 'l', 'm'];

    for (var j = 0; j < units.length; j++) {
        var base = units[j];
        for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
            unitConverter.addUnit(base, prefixes[i] + base, Math.pow(10, factors[i]));
        }
    }

    // we use the SI gram unit as the base; this allows
    // us to convert between SI and English units
    unitConverter.addUnit('g', 'ounce', 28.3495231);
    unitConverter.addUnit('g', 'oz', 28.3495231);
    unitConverter.addUnit('g', 'pound', 453.59237);
    unitConverter.addUnit('g', 'lb', 453.59237);


    window.$u = function (value, unit) {
        var u = new window.unitConverter(value, unit);
        return u;
    };
})();

console.log($u(1, 'g').as('kg').debug());  
console.log($u(1, 'kg').as('g').debug());
console.log($u(1, 'g').as('mg').debug());
console.log($u(1, 'mg').as('g').debug());
console.log($u(1, 'mg').as('kg').debug());

console.log($u(1, 'g').as('oz').debug());
console.log($u(1, 'g').as('lb').debug());

console.log($u(1, 'oz').as('lb').debug());

console.log($u(1, 'lb').as('g').debug());

// this last one throws an exception since you can't convert liters to mg
console.log($u(1, 'l').as('mg').debug());
```

I've moved this to a small repo on Github so if anyone wants to improve/enhance they can do so:
https://github.com/jerodvenemafm/jsunitconverter

Answer (score 9):

You might check out this port of Ruby Units to Javascript:

https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities

Comment: FYI - At the time of this comment, they have had temperature conversion broken with an issue logged against it for a year. I have sent them a pull request to fix it, but until they do, this one works: https://github.com/rage-shadowman/js-quantities

Comment: I find this library to be a bit buggy, which is not a good thing when working with engineering calculations! I have higher hopes for PQM.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pqm), it's syntax is a bit awkward, because you have to bracket prefixes, ( like [k]m ), but this makes it impossible to create the wrong unit on accident. Also, it is tested against a NIST publication on unit conversions, so I have a bit more faith in the results.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by many posts regarding this subject and the simplicity and smallness of [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/) i have started work on this:

[MeasurementJs](https://github.com/Philzen/measurement.js)

It doesn't include all of the mentioned conversions yet, but you can easily extend the `DEFINITIONS` array and `MeasurementJs.Units.*` objects for any possible conversion you like.

Answer (score 4):

I'll just leave this here ...

### Simple JS Method to Convert almost ALL Imperial/Standard measurements of Distance/Length

```
;;if (!window.hasOwnProperty('convertImperialMetric')) {
    function convertImperialMetric () {
        var metrics = convertImperialMetric.metrics,
            imperials = convertImperialMetric.imperials,
            args = arguments,
            conversionTypes = { imperial: 'imperial', metric: 'metric' },
            toFixed = false, toFixedX = 2,
            intX, typImp, typMet, conType = 'metric',
            $ret;

        conversionTypes.i = conversionTypes.imp = conversionTypes.imperial;
        conversionTypes.m = conversionTypes.met = conversionTypes.metric;

        function setVarz(c) {
            for (i in c) {
                var a = c[i];
                switch (typeof a) {
                    case "boolean":
                        toFixed = a;
                        break;
                    case "number":
                        void 0 == intX ? intX = a : toFixedX = a;
                        break;
                    case "string":
                        isNaN(parseFloat(a)) || void 0 != intX ? imperials.hasOwnProperty(a) ? typImp = a : metrics.hasOwnProperty(a) ? typMet = a : conversionTypes.hasOwnProperty(a) && (conType = conversionTypes[a]) : intX = parseFloat(a);
                        break;
                    case "object":
                        if (a instanceof Array) setVarz.apply(this, [a]);
                        else if (a instanceof Object)
                            for (h in a) {
                                var b = a[h];
                                conversionTypes.hasOwnProperty(h) ? conType = conversionTypes[h] : imperials.hasOwnProperty(h) ? (typImp =
                                    h, void 0 != intX || isNaN(parseFloat(b)) || (intX = parseFloat(b))) : metrics.hasOwnProperty(h) ? (typMet = h, void 0 != intX || isNaN(parseFloat(b)) || (intX = parseFloat(b))) : setVarz.apply(this, [
                                    [b]
                                ])
                            }
                }
            }
        };
        setVarz(args);

        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(intX)) && imperials.hasOwnProperty(typImp) && metrics.hasOwnProperty(typMet) && conversionTypes.hasOwnProperty(conType)) {
            if (conType == 'metric') {
                var inches = intX * imperials[typImp],
                    centimeters = inches * 2.54;
                $ret = centimeters * metrics[typMet];
            }
            else if (conType == 'imperial') {
                var centimeters = intX / metrics[typMet],
                    inches = centimeters / 2.54;
                $ret = inches / imperials[typImp];
            }
        }

        return toFixed ? parseFloat($ret.toFixed(toFixedX)) : $ret;
    }

    convertImperialMetric.imperials = {
        inches: 1,
        feet: 12,
        yards: 36,
        miles: 63360,
        nautical: 72913.4
    };

    convertImperialMetric.metrics = {
        yocto: 10000000000000000000000,
        zepto: 10000000000000000000,
        atto: 10000000000000000,
        femto: 10000000000000,
        pico: 10000000000,
        nano: 10000000,
        micro: 10000,
        milli: 10,
        centi: 1,
        deci: .1,
        meter: .01,
        deka: .001,
        hecto: .0001,
        kilo: .00001,
        mega: .00000001,
        giga: .00000000001,
        tera: .00000000000001,
        peta: .00000000000000001,
        exa: .00000000000000000001,
        zetta: .00000000000000000000001,
        yotta: .00000000000000000000000001
    };
}
```

### Example Usages:

```
convertImperialMetric(12, 'inches', 'centi');   //  Results in: 30.48
convertImperialMetric(30.48, 'centi', 'inches', 'i');   //  Results in: 12
convertImperialMetric('1200000', 'inches', 'kilo'); //  Results in: 30.480000000000004
convertImperialMetric('1200000', 'inches', 'kilo', true);   //  Results in: 30.48
convertImperialMetric('1200000', 'inches', 'kilo', true, 1);    //  Results in: 30.5
convertImperialMetric([ 12, 'inches', 'centi' ]);   //  Results in: 30.48
convertImperialMetric([ '12', 'inches', 'centi' ]); //  Results in: 30.48
convertImperialMetric({ inches: 12, anyVariableName: 'centi' });    //  Results in: 30.48
convertImperialMetric({ inches: '12', anyVariableName: 'centi' });  //  Results in: 30.48
convertImperialMetric({ inches: 12, centi: 'anyValue' });   //  Results in: 30.48
convertImperialMetric({ inches: '12', centi: 'anyValue' }); //  Results in: 30.48
convertImperialMetric({ inches: '12', to: 'centi', type: 'metric', toFixed: true, toFX: 1 });   //  Results in: 30.5
convertImperialMetric({ feet: 1 }, 'centi');    //  Results in: 30.48
convertImperialMetric({ centi: '30.48' }, 'inches', 'imperial');    //  Results in: 12
convertImperialMetric({ meter: '.3048' }, 'inches', 'imperial');    //  Results in: 12
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/qbt2du01/) / [jsFiddle/show](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/qbt2du01/show/)**

Answer (score 4):

A popular utility that lets you convert between different units: [convert-units](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-units)

Usage example, converting imperial inches to metric cm:

```
var convert = require('convert-units')
convert(1).from('in').to('cm') // 2.54
```

To install:

```
npm install convert-units
```

Answer (score 3):

How many different units are being converted? It sounds as though you are writing an specific application which I'm taking as you only need a few different types of conversion (area, volume, etc)

*If* this is the case, it might be faster just to look up the conversion for those that you need and code them into a class for yourself. Loading a complete javascript library just to perform a few specific multiplications could be overkill.

Comment: There are many apps that make up the system, each calculating and showing different values (temperature, volume, lengths, areas, etc). I want to not write specific conversion routines in each and just have one library (as bloated as that seems) that I can rely on from within any app.

Answer (score 2):

The library "measure" converts between unit types (volume, mass, etc.) and supports multiple unit systems (US, Imperial, Metric)

```js
// volume
measure('1 teaspoon').teaspoons() // 1
measure('1 1/2 tsp.').teaspoons() // 1.5
measure('2 cups and 1 pint').quarts() // 1

// mass
measure('1 pound').ounces() // 16
measure('1 1/2 oz.').ounces() // 1.5

// operations
measure('1 teaspoon').add('1 teaspoon').teaspoons();
measure('6 1/2 teaspoon').divide(2).teaspoons(); // 3.25
```

https://github.com/dubbs/measure

Answer (score 1):

Here's something extensible and terse that builds a lookup table so performance should be good.

```
core = {};
core.mixin = function (dst, src) { if (src) for (var i in src) dst[i] = src[i]; return dst; }

function UnitConverter(meter) {
    var feetPerMeter = 3.2808399, feetPerMile = 5280;
    this.meter = core.mixin({ km: 1000, mi: feetPerMile / feetPerMeter, ft: 1 / feetPerMeter, m: 1 }, meter);
    var t = [], i = 0;
    for (t[i++] in this.meter);
    this.table = [];
    for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
            var key1 = t[i], key2 = t[(i + j + 1) % t.length];
            this.table[key1 + "/" + key2] = this.meter[key2] / this.meter[key1];
        }
};

with(UnitConverter) {
    prototype = new Object();
    prototype.convert = function () {
        switch (arguments.length) {
        case 1:
            return this.table[arguments[0]];
        case 2:
            return arguments[0] * this.table[arguments[1]];
        case 3:
            return arguments[0] * this.meter[arguments[1]] / this.meter[arguments[2]];
        }
        return Number.NaN;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Number.converter = new UnitConverter({ nm: 1852 }); // extent to include nautical miles
Number.units = Number.converter.table;
var km = 1;
var mi = km * Number.units["mi/km"];
var m = Number.converter.convert(mi, "mi", "m");
var ft = Number.converter.convert(m, "ft/m");
m = Number.converter.convert(ft, "ft", "m");
ft = m / Number.converter.convert("m/ft");
km = ft * Number.units["km/ft"];
nm = Number.converter.convert(km, "km", "nm");
```