# Unit conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question concerning number conversion i JS. I have a number like 1613841.93424 (meters) and I would like it to convert to 1.6 km instead. What JS function should I use for that? Thanks.

Comment: That's not number conversion - that's unit conversion.  The number, in absolute terms, is the same.

Comment: isn't 1613841.93424 (meters) = 1613.84193424 (km) ? 1 km = 1000 meters right ? how can the number specified in the post be equal to 1.6 km !?

Comment: Yeah I got that wrong. it's 1613 km:)

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865590/unit-of-measure-conversion-library/3531444

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit of Measure Conversion Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865590/unit-of-measure-conversion-library)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To convert from metres to kilometres, simply divide by 1000. To format a number using fixed-point notation, you can use the [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core%5FJavaScript%5F1.5%5FReference/Global%5FObjects/Number/toFixed) method:

```
var km = 1613841.93424 / 1000;
alert(km.toFixed(1) + " km"); // 1613.8 km
```

**Note:** 1613841.93424 meters != 1.6 km ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilometre))

Comment: Yeah, it's 1613, I was writing without thinking;)

Answer (score 3):

To display with one number to the right of the decimal (if that is what you're asking..I'm guessing you know how to convert m to km) :

```
.toFixed(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

1613841.93424 m = 1613,841.93424 km

Simply divide by 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.round:

```
m = 1613841.93424;
var km = Math.round(m / 100) / 10;
// km = 1613.8
```

This will give a result rounded to 1/10th km

Comment: round is not defined. Use Math.round.

Answer (score 1):

i usually deal with float padding numbers with a function of my own

```
var zeroPad = function(num, pad){
  var pd = Math.pow(10,pad);
  return Math.floor(num*pd)/pd; 
}
alert(zeroPad(1.32878,3)); // outputs 1,328
alert(zeroPad(1.32878,1)); // outputs 1,3
```

Then finally to convert to kms divide by 1000, apply zeroPad and solved
example :

```
var m = 1613841.93424;
var km = zeroPad(m/1000,3);
alert(km); // outputs 1613.841
```

Comment: Funny how your function doesn't actually pads with zeros, but instead does the same thing as Number.toFixed :)

Comment: @Alsciende its true, i tried right now, i will remember that next time, surely i have a lot of functions in my code that can be solved with native code, but im still learning