# How to change the units from mm to inch or vice versa in angularjs for drop down choose

Tags: angularjs

> Blockquote
>   I need one drop down where user can select any unit(either MM or Inches.toggle),so if i choose the value mm, in my below form all calculation should be done in mm.it means all value should be displayed in mm.and calculated as per unit selected in drop down.
>   eg. length,width and total area all will will be displayed and calculated in MM (based on drop down select)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
     <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Select a unit:</p>
<select ng-model="selectedunit" ng-options="x for (x, y) in unit">
     </select>
    <form  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    Length:<input type="number" ng-model="choice.length"  />
    width: <input type="number" ng-model="choice.width"  />
    Area: <input id="area" type="number" placeholder="Area" value="{{ choice.length * choice.width }}" />
    <button  ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>

    </form>
    
     <button  ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
    Result : {{ sum() }}
</div>
    
     <script>
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1', length:0, width: 0}, {id: 'choice2', length:0, width: 0}];

   $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
  };

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
  };

  $scope.sum = function() {
        var sum = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(choice) {
            sum += choice.length * choice.width;
        });
        return sum;
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you write a custom directive to handle everything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your unit variable, in order to access it. 
For example:

```
$scope.unit = ['mm', 'inch'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> I modified your code just a little bit. Hope it helps!!

1. Added Options {mm, cm, m} with id to be used as Division Factor.
2. Used Options in ng-options on Dropdown.
3. Store previous results and updates the values using ng-change() event

```js
 var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.change = function() {
     if ($scope.data.previousSel != $scope.data.selectedOption) {
       var diff = $scope.data.previousSel.id - $scope.data.selectedOption.id;
       angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(choice) {
         choice.length = Math.pow(10, diff) * choice.length;

         choice.width = Math.pow(10, diff) * choice.width;
       });
       $scope.data.previousSel = $scope.data.selectedOption;
     }
   };
   $scope.data = {
     availableOptions: [{
       id: '1',
       name: 'mm'
     }, {
       id: '2',
       name: 'cm'
     }, {
       id: '4',
       name: 'm'
     }],
     previousSel: {
       id: '4',
       name: 'm'
     },
     selectedOption: {
       id: '4',
       name: 'm'
     } //This sets the default value of the select in the ui

   };
   $scope.choices = [{
     id: 'choice1',
     length: 0,
     width: 0
   }, {
     id: 'choice2',
     length: 0,
     width: 0
   }];

   $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
     var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
     $scope.choices.push({
       'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
     });
   };

   $scope.removeChoice = function() {
     var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
     $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
   };

   $scope.sum = function() {
     var sum = 0;
     angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(choice) {
       sum += choice.length * choice.width;
     });
     return sum;
   }
 });
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Select a unit:</p>
    <select ng-change="change()" ng-model="data.selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id">
    </select>
    <form data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
      Length:
      <input type="number" ng-model="choice.length" />width:
      <input type="number" ng-model="choice.width" />Area:
      <input id="area" type="number" placeholder="Area" value="{{ choice.length * choice.width }}" />
      <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>

    </form>

    <button ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
    Result : {{ sum() }}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ,you given great idea!!!! but my requirement is change the unit into feet and inches, also,so please can you help in this,how to make this code will be work fir feet and inches??

Comment: if you really need to scale up you can perform something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/27306114/1688718